# Unable to display GraphQL data using Apollo Client in ReactNative

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo-client

I am new to RN development.
I am trying to setup Apollo client to fetch GraphQL data.
I am not able to get the data back.

Here is the code in App.js

```
  import {ApolloProvider} from '@apollo/client';
  import AppNavigator from './app/navigation/AppNavigator';
  import apiClient from './app/api/client';

  function App(props) {
     console.log('From Main Component');
     return (
        <ApolloProvider client={apiClient}>
           <NavigationContainer>
              <AppNavigator />
           </NavigationContainer>
        </ApolloProvider>
     );
   }
```

In AppNavigator, Im displaying only the home screen for now.

In ./app/api/client.js

```
    import {ApolloClient, InMemoryCache} from '@apollo/client';

    const apiClient = new ApolloClient({
        uri: 'https://phccapi-dev.azure-api.net/NaraakomGraphQLGateway/graphql',
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
        headers: {
           authorization:'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
           'Subscription-Key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        },
    });

    export default apiClient;
```

In api/queries.js

```
    import {gql} from '@apollo/client';

    export default {
       GET_USER_NAME,
    };

    //Used in the Home Screen
    const GET_USER_NAME = gql`
        query {
            userProfile {
              fName
              lName
            }
        }
    `;
```

In HomeScreen.js

```
    import DisplayData from '../components/DisplayData';

    function HomeScreen({navigation}) {
        return (
           <View>
              <Text> Home Screen text </Text>
              <DisplayData/>
              <Button title="Profile" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')} />
           </View>
         );
     }

     export default HomeScreen;
```

In DisplayData.js

```
    import {useQuery} from '@apollo/client';
    import GET_USER_NAME from './../api/queries';

    function DisplayData(props) {
      console.log('Logging query : ' + GET_USER_NAME);
      const {loading, error, data} = useQuery(GET_USER_NAME);

      if (loading) {
        console.log('Loading : ' + loading);
        return (
          <View>
            <Text>Loading...</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }

     if (error) {
       console.log('Error : ' + error);
       return (
         <View>
           <Text>Error :</Text>
         </View>
       );
     }

     console.log('Data : ' + data);
     return (
       <View>
          <Text> In Component </Text>
          <Text> {data.userProfile.fName} </Text>
       </View>
     );
    }

    export default DisplayData;
```

From GraphiQL, if I run the query I am getting the data.
If I follow the Apollo Client Documentation https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/get-started/ and put all code in a single file , I am able to get the data

But most tutorials that I have gone through suggest to follow a hierarchy , a folder structure to properly maintain code and separate the concerns as the app grows

Hence I have tried to separate different things in different files and components

But I think I have not been able to set it up properly.

Before learning RN , I have also just learned JS and React

So I am guessing that there could also be some issue in the way I have declared constants/components , exported and imported them

Comment: hello please did you resolve it ?

Comment: Yes I was able to resolve it, what is the issue that you are facing ?